# Why does Powershell -match any string with $null

Tags: powershell, null

Found this while debugging a Powershell script.

```
PS C:\temp> "hello" -match $null  
True
```

But

```
> "hello" -eq $null returns False
```

Why, when using `-match`, any string will match with `$null`?

Comment: Presumably because the `$null` regular expression matches anything because it matches against nothing. Similarly you can insert as many `${null}`s as you want into the middle of a pattern and not affect its matching because they simply expand to nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is because the $null gets coerced to an empty string as `-match` expects a string pattern on the RHS (Right Hand Side). And an empty string will match anything.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah checked and -match with any empty/null variable is True.  Empty strings match anything, learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: This must be correct, for `"hello" -match [NullString]::Value` explodes with an `ArgumentNullException`.